# Can I route all connections on my router through a VPN?

Tags: security, vpn, openvpn, dd-wrt

I have a Cisco Linksys e1200v2 with DD-WRT v24sp2 mega. I would like to have all connections go through the OpenVPN server that I already have configured. I have noticed the Open VPN Server and Open VPN Client options under Services, however I'm not sure this is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a laptop from another location (eg: Library or coffee shop) then you can use your router OpenVPN server to encrypt your connection while in that location.
If you are using a computer from your home, where the router is, then there is no reason to use your router OpenVPN as the only place the data is encrypted is on your physical LAN.
You need to understand what a VPN is and how it can help you: See the [OpenVPN Documentation](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation.html)